# Subclipse : Package explorer doesn't show packages, it shows file directory view :(

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have a problem regarding Subclipse and the Eclipse Package Explorer. The svn update-progress itself works perfect, however when I restart Eclipse after having updated the sources with Subclipse, the Eclipse Package Explorer shows every file/directory as if it was a single package. Thus the view is confusing. Is this a known problem? Does anyone know a fix? Thanks in advance Kapila

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you mean it shows intermediate packages (e.g. org, org.apache, org.apache.junit etc.), you can restore the Eclipse filters to hide empty parent packages and hide .* resources (such as the .svn folders). It seems to be a feature of Subclipse that it messes with the filters sometimes.

To do so open the **Filters...** dialog by selecting the downwards-pointing triangle in the package explorer view.

[filters screenshot http://wiki.objectstyle.org/confluence/download/attachments/3385/packageExplorer-filters.jpg](http://wiki.objectstyle.org/confluence/download/attachments/3385/packageExplorer-filters.jpg)

Then ensure .* and/or .svn-base are selected. This will hide them from view.

[image: select .* resources]

In the same dialog you can select that **Empty parent packages** be hidden if not already.

[image: empty parent packages filter]
<sub>(source: [eclipse.org](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-2.1-200303272130/images/non-shared-project-filter.gif))</sub>

Comment: @Kapalia, you are very welcome. If you so choose you can accept this answer by clicking on the tick at the top left of the answer